# Asynchronous S3 PutBucketRequests appear to be executing in series

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, amazon-s3

I'm working on improving the upload performance of a .net app that uploads groups of largeish (~15mb each) files to S3.

I have adjusted multipart options (threads, chunk size, etc.) and I think I've improved that as much as possible, but while closely watching the network utilization, I noticed something unexpected.

I iterate over a number of files in a directory and then submit each of them for upload using an instance of the S3 transfer utility like so:

```
//  prepare the upload
this._transferUtility.S3Client.PutBucket(new PutBucketRequest().WithBucketName(streamingBucket));

 request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
   .WithBucketName(streamingBucket)
   .WithFilePath(streamFile)
   .WithKey(targetFile)
   .WithTimeout(uploadTimeout)
   .WithSubscriber(this.uploadFileProgressCallback);

 //  start the upload
 this._transferUtility.Upload(request);
```

Then I watch for these to complete in the uploadFileProgressCallback specified above.

However when I watch the network interface, I can see a number of distinct "humps" in my outbound traffic graph which coincide precisely with the number of files I'm uploading to S3.

Since this is an asynchronous call, I was under the impression that each transfer would begin immediately, and I'd see a stepped increase in outbound data followed by a stepped decrease as each upload was completed.  Base on what I'm seeing now I wonder if these requests, while asynchronous to the calling code, are being queued up somewhere and then executed in series?

If so I'd like to change that so the request all begin uploading at (close to) the same time, so I can maximize the upload bandwidth I have available and reduce the overal execution time.

I poked around in the S3 .net SDK documentation but I couldn't find any mention of this queueing mechanism or any properties/etc. that appeared to provide a way of increasing the concurrency of these calls.

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is something that's not intrinsically supported by the SDKs due to simplicity requirements maybe? I implemented my own concurrent part uploads based on this article. 
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/amazon-s3-multipart-upload.html

Some observations:

1. This approach is good only when you have the complete content in memory as you have to break it into chunks and wrap it up in part uploads. In many cases it may not make sense to have order of GBs of data in memory just so that you can do concurrent uploads. You may have to evaluate the tradeoff there.
2. SDKs have a limit of upto 16MB for a singlePut upload and any file size beyond this value would be divided into 5MB chunks for part uploads. Unfortunately these values are not configurable. So I had to pretty much write my own multipart upload logic. The values mentioned above are for the java SDK and I'd expect these to be the same for the C# one too.
3. All operations are non-blocking which is good.

Answer (score 0):

In c# you could try to set the partsize manually.

```
TransferUtilityUploadRequest request =
            new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
                .WithPartSize(??).
```

Or

```
TransferUtilityConfig utilityConfig = new TransferUtilityConfig();
       utilityConfig.MinSizeBeforePartUpload = ??;
```

But i don't know the defaults